GraalVM Native thread dump?
I've seen some methods for how to do a heap dump on a GraalVM Native application, but how do you do a thread (stack) dump? Apparently, the usual jstack isn't an option, since it's a native app, but I'd like to get a similar result, in whatever form GraalVM Native is capable of.
